# ImageView maxHeight is not consistent

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-glide

I have an ImageView inside an RelativeLayout with maxHeight defined.
I am loading the image into this ImageView using Glide

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_View_Pic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:maxHeight="200dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

First I see the Imageview height is correctly working, but if I go to another activity and come back to this activity the same image height further reduces less than 200dp sometimes

I have no clue why is it happening ? Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the issue was because of maxheight but I was wrong

Instead I found the issue was with Glide, it was changing the original drawable's pixel on reload as a result I was getting different sized image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this attribute in addition to the `android:maxHeight="200dp"` attribute 
and let me know if this was helpful :

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: as you can see in my code i already have  android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: My mistake, I was sure you didnt had this